# Time of the revelation of verse 9:5

Tags: hadith, history

[Sahih bukhari 4355](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4355) says:

> Narrated Jarir:
> In the Pre-lslamic Period of Ignorance there was a house called Dhu-l-Khalasa or Al-Ka'ba Al- Yamaniya or Al-Ka`ba Ash-Shamiya. The Prophet (ﷺ) said to me, "Won't you relieve me from Dhu-l- Khalasa?" So I set out with one-hundred-and-fifty riders, and we dismantled it and killed whoever was present there. Then I came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and informed him, and he invoked good upon us and Al- Ahmas (tribe) .

Was this Hadith before or after the verse 9:5?

Answer (score 3):

The time at which Ghazwa Dhul-Khalasa took place is not known with precision.

Jarir bin 'Abdullah al-Bajali (the narrator of the hadith) was among those sahaba who accepted Islam near the end of the ministry of the Prophet ﷺ, as he was from Yemen and came to visit the Prophet ﷺ with the delegations. There are different reports on exactly when he accepted Islam, however it is likely that it happened in the year 9 AH, while other reports also say 10 AH or even 11 AH. He obviously led the expedition to Dhul Khalasa after his conversion to Islam.

> اختلف في إسلامه والصحيح أنه في سنة الوفود سنة تسع
>
> There is difference on when he accepted Islam and what is correct is that it was in the year of delegations - the ninth year
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/index.php/book/1673/3873), also see  [Al-Isabah fi tamyiz al Sahabah](https://shamela.ws/book/9767/567)</sup>

Verse 9:5 was also revealed at roughly the same time. This happened at the occasion of the Hajj that took place under Abu Bakr in the year 9 AH. In this Hajj the polytheists were permitted to come for the last time and at this occasion the Prophet ﷺ sent Ali ibn Abi Talib to recite to them the verses of Surah at-Tawbah and to annul the treaties made with them. See e.g. [Bukhari:369](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:369) , [Nasai 2958](https://sunnah.com/nasai:2958), [Tirmidhi 3092](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3092).

> بعث رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أبا بكر أميرًا على الموسم سنة تسع, وبعث عليّ بن أبي طالب، رضي الله عنهما، بثلاثين أو أربعين آية من براءة
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ sent Abu Bakr as the leader of the Hajj in the ninth year, and sent Ali ibn Abu Talib with them with thirty or forty* verses of Baraa’ah (Surah at-Tawbah)
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Tabary](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura9-aya1.html#tabary)</sup>
>
> *<sup>(**Note:** there are different reports about the number of verses which were sent, but the minimum report states that it included at least the first nine verses, as recorded in e.g. [Tafsir Muqatil ibn Sulayman](https://shamela.ws/book/23614/542))</sup>

Given the above it is *possible* that the expedition took place after the revelation of 9:5 and it is also possible that it happened before. Whereas if we accept the report that Jarir accepted Islam in 10 AH then it much more certain that the expedition took place after the revelation of the verse.

> قال الواقدي: في هذه السنة قدم جرير بن عبد الله البجلي على رسول الله ص مسلما في رمضان، فبعثه رسول الله إلى ذي الخلصة فهدمها
>
> Waqidi said: In this year (10 AH) Jarir bin 'Abdullah al-Bajali came to the Messenger of Allah ﷺ as a Muslim in the month of Ramadan, and the prophet sent him to Dhul Khalasa and demolished it
>
> <sup>— [Tarikh at-Tabari](https://shamela.ws/book/9783/1432)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Asalaam Alaikum

to find an answer to your question, let us examin the verse and the incident separately. in the books of tafsir, there are mentions about when the verse 9:5 (verse of the sword) was revealed and in books of history it is mentioned the incident of destruction of dhul-khalasa. let us try to find a time-lime, insha Allah.

in the tafsir of ibn kathir,

> The first part of this honorable Surah was revealed to the Messenger of Allah when he returned from the battle of Tabuk, during the Hajj season, which the Prophet thought about attending.

now if we try to find the when the battle of tabuk took place, in the books of islamic history it is mentioned **9 AH, that is 630 AD.** (in some books it is mentioned that it was the month of october/rajab)

now let us look at the incident of dhul-khalasa. in the books of islamic history it is mentioned that this incident occured on **10 AH, that is 632 AD.** (here i found no relevant month mentioned)

from this we can understand for ourselves if the verse or hadith precedes, insha Allah.

(note : this research was purely my own and if there is any mistake, its by me. may Allah help me.)

may Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

Allah knows best.

REFERENCE :

- tafsir of the quran by ibn kathir
- al-bidaya wa'l-nihaya by ibn kathir
- al-sira al nabawiyya by ibn kathir
- atlas of the islamic conquests published by darussallam